# Does NHibernate's ISession.QueryOver fire any events?

Tags: c#, events, nhibernate, event-handling, isession

I have only recently learned about the Events system in NHibernate.  The [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#events) says that

> Essentially all of the methods of the ISession interface correlate to an event

and yet I cannot find any event that fires when I load a List of objects with ISession.QueryOver().List().  I would've thought that this fairly common operation would have a nice event associated with it, but I've tested  InitializeCollectionEvent, RefreshEvent, LoadEvent, and a couple others, and none of them fire when I call QueryOver(), so what am I missing?

If there's really no event raised by QueryOver(), then what operation raises the InitializeCollectionEvent?  I just want to handle whenever a list of objects is loaded from the db, and I assume that this is the event I'll need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it looks like ISession.QueryOver().List() fires the PostLoadEvent once for each object in the returned list, I just forgot to register the listeners with my NHibernate Configuration during testing :P  There are probably additional events fired but I didn't check any others.

Hopefully this helps somebody in the future...